# DJI android sdk camera profile

Tags: dji-sdk

Does anyone know the profile of the RAW 264 format from the camera through the API? Is it main or is it possible to change to baseline profile in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Which camera and drone are you using?

I don't believe there is a way to know and change the H.264 profile - if I hear something different I'll update this post.  But in general the video and storage settings can be played with here: [method loadSettingsFromProfile](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Camera/DJICamera.html?search=profile&i=69&#djicamera_camerasettings_loadsettings_inline)

If this doesn't help, then email dev@dji.com describing in detail what you want to do (include which SDK you would like to use) and what DJI products you're using - we can look into making this a feature request.